# A simple regex expression to omit leading zeros

Tags: ruby, regex

I would think this should be really simple..

I want to do this:

```
date_num = '09'.gsub(/<match the zero>/, '')

date_num = '20'.gsub(/<same expression should not match the zero>/, '')
```

What is the best way of doing this in Ruby?

Comment: Are the strings guaranteed to be integer strings?  If so, you could just do `.to_i.to_s`

Comment: yes they are. that is remarkably useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\A0+(?=\d)
```

I haven't used ruby but if Regex is still Regex then that right there should match just leading 0's. The ^ tells it to look at the front of the string and then looks for a group of 0's to be the first elements. It will match 00000032423 but not 23000000

EDIT:
Added John and Jorg's comments into the solution

Comment: In Ruby, `^` is start-of-line, not start-of-string. Start-of-string is `\A`.

Comment: What about `'00'.gsub`...? Could add a lookahead [^0+(?=\d)](https://regex101.com/r/eY0dA7/1) to not eat too much.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a negative look-behind to prevent a match on zeros that are preceded by a non-zero digit. This does not require the numerical part to be at the beginning of the string.

```
r = /(?<![1-9])0+(?=[1-9])/

'string A 09'.gsub(r, '')       #=> "string A 9"
'string B 20'.gsub(r, '')       #=> "string B 20"
'string C 00000020'.gsub(r, '') #=> "string C 20"
'string D 0'.gsub(r, '')        #=> "string D 0"
'string E 0a'.gsub(r, '')       #=> "string E 0a"
'Agent 007'.gsub(r, '')         #=> "Agent 7"
```

Edit: I added a positive look-ahead to deal with the penultimate and antepenultimate examples. I think @pguardiario has a better solution, though I might be inclined to replace his `\B` with the look-ahead I'm now using here.

Comment: This is a better solution than mine, it works for strings that aren't just numbers

Answer (score 1):

You can probably get it with just word boundaries:

```
'09 20 008 2020 0'.gsub(/\b0+\B/, '')
#=> "9 20 8 2020 0"
```

but you might want to check for decimals as well:

```
'00002.0002'.gsub(/(?<!\.)\b0+\B/, '')
#=> "2.0002"
```

Comment: A word boundary seem desirable, as `"A0152"` probably should not be modified, but on the other hand: `"$07.50"`...

Comment: I'm glad you agree :) Also, a `0` should not get hosed.

Comment: I just realized that `"$07.50" `  is not such a good example for "on the other hand"....

Comment: Are you arguing with me? I can't tell. In any case mine works for common cases like `0` and `1.01` while yours does not, so for that reason it's probably better.

Comment: I agree with you. I was just musing ("turning something over in the mind meditatively and often inconclusively"), as I'm prone to do.

Comment: Ah, I now understand your earlier "hosed" reference, which presumably is the reason for `"\B"`.  I did an edit to address that, but did it a little differently.